# Draw arrows between two circles using svg

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am using svg to draw several arcs with arcs on the end between 2 circles with the help of Bezier quadratic path.
Here is the final effect I want to achieve.
http://www.apcjones.com/arrows/

I already had some idea about how to draw several arcs(without arrows) between two circles.

But when I tried to draw several arcs(with arrows on the end) between 2 circles, something weird happened. 
I am using  here and I set refX to "radius" of the circle to offset the line inside the circle. But I soon realized that simply using refX does not solve the problem, the angle of the marker should also be adjusted(I do not know how).

[current effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiGep.png)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Any code? I've lost my crystal ball

Comment: I want to ahieve this. http://www.apcjones.com/arrows/

Comment: What about your code?

Comment: Please update your question and provide a [mcve]

Comment: It looks like your markers have not been defined properly. Most likely your `refx` and/or `refy` are incorrect.  But we can't help you debug code which to us is imaginary.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you may need to use [markers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker).

```html
<svg width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <defs>
    <desc>Define the marker</desc>
    <marker id="arrow" refX="4" refY="3" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto" stroke="black">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 4 3 L 0 6 Z"></path>
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <desc>Use the markers</desc>
  <circle cx="160" cy="50" r="20" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" />
  
  <line x1="70" y1="50" x2="140" y2="50" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" marker-end="url(#arrow)"></line>

</svg>
```

If you need more help please edit your question and add your SVG code

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But I am using bezier curves and also I have a lot of circles with dynamic positions. Examples with static values do not help..

Comment: The SVG marker is able to adapt. You can use it with Bézier curves too.  Please add a simplified version of your code.